# Use jest to write tests with flow

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, flowtype

I am trying to test a React Native module that I built using jest. I currently have a test file that runs when I execute `jest`, it looks like this:

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import {MySDK} from 'react-native-mysdk’


it(‘test1’, () => {
  MySDK.API();
});
```

When I run `jest` I get

```
      API(): Promise<string> {
                        ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

My babel.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

And my package.json looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.3",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.3.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.92.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3”,
   “react-native-mysdk”: “0.0.1”
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "16.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "16.0.2",
    "jest-react-native": "16.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

I've tried to update my babel file with:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset", "@babel/preset-flow"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

but I get the same error.

How can I use jest with javascript files that use jest?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types` plugin to remove the flow types when running the tests. Install it and add it to your babel config file as a plugin array item. Alternatively you can use the `@babel/preset-flow` which already includes the required plugin.

See: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-flow

#### Example setup

You need to install the following packages:

```js
npm i --save jest module:metro-react-native-babel-preset babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/core @babel/preset-flow
```

Your `package.json` config for `jest` should be:

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Your `babel.config.js` should be:

```js
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        }
      },
    ],
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
}
```

Comment: I added example above, please try that and let me know if it works